# acf block global style.css not showning, forced to use inline css in block.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

So the styles I write in VDW/library/css/style.css do not show on the front-end for the blocks I make in VDW/template-parts/block/hero-banner-block.php. The following code should call the style.css but it doesn't work, VDW/library/acf_blocks.php. and yes i have require_once('library/acf_blocks.php'); in my functions.php.

acf_blocks.php:

```
<?php

function vdw_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );
    add_editor_style( 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    add_editor_style( 'library/css/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'vdw_setup' );

function custom_category( $categories, $post ){
    return array_merge(
        $categories,
        array(
            array(
                'slug' => 'custom',
                'title' => __( 'Custom', 'custom' ),
            ),
        )
        );
}

add_filter( 'block_categories', 'custom_category', 10, 2 );

function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block ) {
    $slug = str_replace('acf/', '', $block['name']);

    if( file_exists( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/{$slug}.php") ) ){
        include( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/{$slug}.php") );
    }
}

add_action('acf/init', 'my_acf_init');

function my_acf_init(){
    if( function_exists('acf_register_block') ){
        
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name' => 'hero-banner-block',
            'title' => __('Hero banner Block'),
            'description' => __('Hero banner voor bovenaan de pagina'),
            'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
            'category' => 'custom',
            'icon' => 'embed-photo',
            'keywords' => array( 'page', 'posts' )
        ));
        
        acf_register_block(array(
            'name' => 'drie-kolom-block',
            'title' => __('Drie blokken Block'),
            'description' => __('Drie blokken blok voor paginas'),
            'render_callback' => 'my_acf_block_render_callback',
            'category' => 'custom',
            'icon' => 'columns',
            'keywords' => array( 'page', 'posts' )
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

hero-banner-block.php:

```
<?php /* Block Name: Hero banner Block */  ?>
<style>

.containerd{
    margin-top:0px!important;
    position: relative;
    background-position: 50%;
    min-height: 430px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset, rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 50px 100px -20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 30px 60px -30px;
}
.bl{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.bl-1{
    padding: 1.5rem;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.bl-2{
    flex-basis: 66.66%;
}
@media (max-width: 781px){
.bl-1 {
    flex-basis: 100%!important;
}}
.bg-image-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    z-index: 0;
}
</style>
    <?php 
            $link = get_field('afbeelding');
            if( $link ):
                $link_url = $link['url'];
                ?>
<div class="containerd">
        <img class="bg-image-1" src="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" alt="">
        <div style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="bl">
                <div class="bl-1">
                    <h1 class="has-large-font-size"><?php the_field('titel'); ?></h1>
                    <p><?php the_field('text'); ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="bl-2">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tried loading the styles individually in the functions.php but that did not work either.